# JavaFx Source Code Auto Formatting

Tags: netbeans, javafx

Question simple and quick:
I have started to use Netbeans to write some code on JavaFx.

I couldn't find working shortcut to make code beauty (auto formatting shortcut)
Do you know where it is?

PS: Alt + Shift + F doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is a known bug, see [the bug report](http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=160709) at netbeans.org.

Answer (score 1):

It existed in JavaFX 1.0 version of Netbeans, but was buggy so it's been pulled.

There is an eclipse based plugin, but I've not tried it myself.